# Remove Unneeded Spaces from JSON Output

Tags: c#, .net, json, formatting, json.net

I am sterilizing a JSON.Net object, and it contains many arrays. Here is the output I currently get:

```
"children": [ 
{ 
      "children": [ 
      {
      },
      {
      }
}
```

However, just for the ease of reading and comparing, I would like to remove the line breaks between each brace and bracket and between the comma and next brace, so it looks like this:

```
"children": [ { 
      "children": [ {

      }, {
      }
}
```

I am already sterilizing my JSON with the `Formatting.Indented` argument, so I would like to know if there is another setting I can change so that JSON.Net sterilizes without the extra line brakes, but retaining the indented formatting.

Comment: Why the close vote? Many people want an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no feature in Json.NET to give you that kind of indentation. You'll either have to do it yourself outside of Json.NET or modify the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you split on '{' and then join the array again by spaces?